# TYPO3: Hide record if logged-in user is NOT part of a user group

Tags: typo3

I have a record that I want to **hide** only if the frontend user is logged in AND he is part of a specific user group. How can I do that?
The opposite is very easy with the "Access" tab... but this I can't figure out.. is there a way to do it with typoscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to get your hands dirty, writing some TypoScript Conditions instead of using the graphical method.

- http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/references/doc_core_tsref/4.4.0/view/1/4/#id2315154

Hope it helps you. If there is a graphical method, I sure would like to know about it since every now and then it might come in handy.

cu
Roman

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in the TCE Form. But you'll have to create two seperated user-groups. So, when you assign a content element to fe group "A" it will be automatically hidden for "B".

This would be the opposite, then.